# How do I get 2 place decimal without rounding off in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make output that will display only 2 decimal points without rounding it off, I have tried method cast, but I think I do it wrongly.

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT amount, amount - ((((amount-10)/106)*100)*(0.1)) AS paynet,
CAST(((amount - ((((amount-10)/106)*100)*(0.1))))as decimal(10,2)) AS pay_to
FROM tbl_paid
WHERE kode = '1234Q';
```

`paynet` and `pay_to` is the calculation using the row value of `amount`

When I do this query, I got this output

[image: the output based on the query]

What I want to achieve is I want the `pay_to` value = `433.40` and not `433.41`

How do I fix this query ?

Comment: More info here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html

Comment: Use TRUNCATE(): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate instead of CAST or ROUND